# merging matrix columns that exists inside a numerical list

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have created a list like the following one that contains all combinations of a specific character inside a string. The code that creates the list is as follows :

```
library(stringr)
test = str_locate_all("TTEST" , "T")
ind1 = lapply( lapply(1:nrow(test[[1]]), combn , x=test[[1]][,1])  , t )
ind1[[1]] = rbind(ind1[[1]], 0 )
```

and the list that I'm getting looks like

```
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    5
[4,]    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    5
[3,]    2    5

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    5
```

what I want now is to combine/collapse the columns (where ever are more than one) and unlist the whole object in order to create a final vector that will look like c(1, 2, 5, 0, 1:2, 1:5, 2:5, 1:2:5 ) and be able to use it with expand.grid() function later.

Tried to solve it with the following code partially but ":" character went on different position than the wanted.

```
do.call(paste, c( as.data.frame(ind1[[2]]) ,collapse=":") )
[1] "1 2:1 5:2 5"
```

Comment: `1:2:5` can be simplified to `1:5`. Can we assume that the values for `[[3]]` always increase column-wise?

Comment: the ":" is just a separator character and doesn't mean 1 to 5. It could be a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea via base R where we convert the list elements to data frames and use `do.call` to paste them, i.e.

```
unlist(lapply(ind1, function(i) do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(i), sep = ':'))))
#[1] "1"     "2"     "5"     "0"     "1:2"   "1:5"   "2:5"   "1:2:5"
```

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking, but those three-element bits will somehow have to be split up.